# Does inline CSS override a stylesheet at the bottom of the page?

Tags: css

I'm building a javascript plugin/CSS sheet that MUST override a page's original styles (the plugin makes any static site responsive).

Currently, if I have something like:

```
<body id="home">
    <div style="width:900px; background:green; height:500px; margin:0 auto;">
        <div style="width:400px; background:blue; height:300px;"
            <p>Hello hello hello hello hello hello</p> 
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div style="width:800px; background:green; height:500px;">
        <div style="float:left; width:400px; background:blue; height:300px;"
            <p>blah blah blah blah blah</p> 
        </div>
    </div>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jq_responsive.css" >
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
```

my jq_responsive.css styles do not take precedence over the inline styles. If I put the inline styles in a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of the document, then apply classes that point to said styles the jq_responsive.css file overrides as it should. However, this isn't an option for my purposes.

Is `!important` the only way I can override here? I'd like to avoid that if at all possible.

Comment: May I ask you, why you even use inline styles?

Comment: it can only override by !important

Comment: The general rule is that the last css rule to be encountered takes precedence, so in this case the css file has precedence for a duplicate style property.

Comment: The `link` element at the end, being inside `body`, violates HTML specifications and may thus be ignored.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela Is there a better place to put it to ensure it takes precedence?

Comment: @Jascination, no, the placement does not make it override inline CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crescent order of specificity

The following list of selectors is by increasing specificity:

- Universal selectors
- Type selectors
- Class selectors
- Attributes selectors
- Pseudo-classes
- ID selectors
- Inline style

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity

!important may be the only way in CSS, or you can use JavaScript to remove the inline CSS

Comment: Interesting. I suppose I'll have to take the inline CSS with javascript and put it into a css file, then remove it from inline. !important won't work in this case, because the styles aren't always meant to take precedence, only more important than inline styles.